# How to write R formula for multivariate response?

Tags: r, regression

In R I want to do some regression on multivariate response on all predictors, for univariate response, I know the formula is like

`y~.,`  this is to use all predictors to regress y, what if now I face 100 response, I can not 
type 100 yi like
 `y1+y2+y3...+y4~x`, 
so how to use all predictors to regress multivariate response?

Comment: [This answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11127/multivariate-multiple-regression-in-r/11132#11132) has an example.

Answer (score 14):

In R, the multivariate [formula](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models) is to use `cbind()` for your `Y` variable.  Thus, the formula would be:

```
model <- lm(cbind(y1, y2, y3, y4)~x)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to encapsulate the `cbind` method in `as.formula`? I would like to create a formula object that would make use of the `cbind` method.

Comment: @Konrad, this seems to work: `heads <- c(50, 25); tails <- c(50, 75); form  <- as.formula(cbind(heads, tails)~c(0,  1)); summary(glm(form, family=binomial))`. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That's relatively easy if `y` is a matrix with 100 columns. In that case you do it the same way. For example:

```
lm(y ~ x)
```

will do a linear regression of y onto the columns of `x`.

Comment: This just fits a separate regression for each column of `y` which effectively assumes independence of the columns of $y$ (conditional on $x$) - is there a way to do general multivariate regression with non-independence association structures? I know you can do multivariate regression in `lme4` by doing univariate regression with correlated errors, but is there a package that will let you do general multivariate regression in a more intuitive way?